# php url/rest boolean logic parser

Tags: php, sql, boolean-logic

Are there any existing php modules/libraries/classes to parse out boolean logic (and, or, not, in, not in, =, <, >, and grouping) from a string/url?

I am creating a rest api into a database and would like to support advanced boolean queries for the column/field values of each object.

My current fallback is to support simple column filters (/object/*/key/val) via php/sql and use our solr instance of the database to support direct solr queries (which has tons of query features). The only problem with this is that solr is not realtime data. It is up to 1-2 minutes stale, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try out parse_str() in php.

For more info about this check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php